# App lock with fingerprint reader support for Android

Tags: android, security

I am looking for a reliable and frequently updated app to lock down other apps/SMS/emails/pictures, which contain sensitive data and it supports fingerprint based authentication.

My device is rooted, I have Xposed framework too, so any recommended app idea could be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this app called ["App Locker - Best App Lock"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.martianmode.applock) on Play and I think it will be fine for me.

Key features:

- fingerprint support
- lightweight
- it can lock Facebook Messenger chat heads
- it can lock gallery and/or pictures
- free
- material design, color themes
- Android 6.0.1 and 7 support